# Which jdk used by spring-boot maven plug-in?

Tags: java, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I build all my java projects with the command :

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

I'd like to know which jdk (and how) is used :

- to build java project
- to run java project

by spring-boot maven plugin ?

In fact, it seems that the jdk should not be the same for the build and the run.

How does it work ?

Comment: It uses the JDK that is currently configured in your environment for both operations. Check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50249466/switch-between-multiple-java-versions-jdk1-8-and-jdk10

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
java --version
```

in your command line. The result must be something like

```
openjdk 17 2021-09-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17+35-2724)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17+35-2724, mixed mode, sharing)
```

This JDK is used for build and run.

Comment: i do not agree. In fact, $PATH and $JAVA_HOME could diverge regarding java binary path content (first match on jdk11 for $PATH, match on jdk8 for $JAVA_HOME). However, maven seems to use $JAVA_HOME when java command use $PATH. So, it seems you're not right.